# Django: Add another subclass in a class based view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

This is my first django app and I was wondering if it is possible to have a general class which will be extended by all Views. For example

```
class GeneralParent:
   def __init__(self):
       #SETTING Up different variables 
       self.LoggedIn = false
   def isLoggedIn(self):
       return self.LoggedIn

class FirstView(TemplateView):
   ####other stuff##
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        allLeads = len(self.getAllLeads())
        context['isLoggedIn'] = ####CALL GENEREAL PARENT CLASS METHOD###

        return context

class SecondView(FormView):
####other stuff##
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        allLeads = len(self.getAllLeads())
        context['isLoggedIn'] = ####CALL GENEREAL PARENT CLASS METHOD###

        return context
```

Is this possible in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of inheritance is important and calls of super cascade down the line of inheritance. You must account for any variables that may be passed down in inheritance in your `__init__` methods.

The first inheritances methods will be called first, and the second as as the `__init__` method of the first parent calls super (in order to call the `__init__` of the second parent). `GeneralParent` must inherit from `object` or a class that inherits from `object`.

```
class GeneralParent(object):
   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       #SETTING Up different variables 
       super(GeneralParent,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       self.LoggedIn = false
   def isLoggedIn(self):
       return self.LoggedIn

class FirstView(GeneralParent,TemplateView):
   ####other stuff##
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FirstView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        allLeads = len(self.getAllLeads())
        context['isLoggedIn'] = ####CALL GENEREAL PARENT CLASS METHOD###

        return context

class SecondView(GeneralParent,FormView):
####other stuff##
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SecondView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        allLeads = len(self.getAllLeads())
        context['isLoggedIn'] = ####CALL GENEREAL PARENT CLASS METHOD###

        return context
```

Comment: It worked, but why does my class needs to inherit from object?

Comment: `super` only works with new-style classes (inheriting from `object`) - more info - https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class