# Django - How To Use Form In Footer

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views, footer

Previously, I had my 'subscribe to newsletter' form on the home page (index.html). However, I moved it to the footer.html in order for it to be shown on every page.

The issue is that since the logic to deal with the form is only in the home view, submitting to the form only works on the home page.

Here is some code to help you understand:

This is in footer.html which is included in base.html which is extended by all other htmls

```
<form class="nwsltr-primary-1" action="." method="POST">  <!-- . means current URL we are on -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email"/>
    <button type="submit"><i class="ion-ios-paperplane"></i></button>
</form>
```

This is what I think needs to change. This is the view for the home page and the only place the logic for the form is being seen:

```
def index(request):
    # featured and object_list get all Posts with featured bool true. order_by=latest first. :6=first 6
    featured = Post.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by('-share_count')[:6]
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:5]
    popular = Post.objects.order_by("-share_count")[:4]

    # Basic but does not do any verification
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]
        new_signup = Signup()
        new_signup.email = email
       new_signup.save()

    context = {
        'object_list': featured,
        'latest': latest,
        'popular': popular
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)  # html page that will be shown
```

How do I make it so that the if statement above can be ran on every page without copying that to every single view?

Comment: Are you creating the form manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas how to solve this problem:

1. You could put the logic for the form in an extra function and call this function in each view-function you need it
2. You could use class based views and make a 'general superclass' that holds your form logic. All the 'subclasses' inherit from the superclass after. Here is a link with an example: [General superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971188/django-add-another-subclass-in-a-class-based-view)